# How to reset the SneakyJoyStick back to its centered position?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, reset, joystick, touches

I need to know how to reset the SneakyJoyStick back to its original centered position. The problem that I'm having is I have the joystick controlling my player and when the player reaches a door tile on a TMX map I have it push the new scene/map, problem occurs when I try to leave the new scene/map because when I pop the scene (to get back to the first scene) the joystick is still stuck in the direction of the door so it pushes me in again so I essentially cannot leave the room. I think it has something to do with the fact that thats where I was last touching the screen so maybe I need to clear touches or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround if others had the same question, in `SneakyJoystick.h` if you change `@property (nonatomic, readonly) CGPoint velocity;` to `@property (nonatomic, readwrite) CGPoint velocity;` then you can `JoyStickName.velocity = CGPointZero;` to reset the velocity.
Changing `@property (nonatomic, readonly) CGPoint stickPosition;` in  `SneakyJoystick.h` to `@property (nonatomic, readwrite) CGPoint stickPosition;` then using `JoyStickName.stickPosition = CGPointZero;` will reset the actual 'stick' image.